# TIdFTP.GET, What is the correct way to refer to the file in the remote folder?

Tags: delphi, get, ftp, indy

I am trying to use TIdFTP.Get (version 10) to download a file (ssleay32.dll) from a remote server where I have an account.

The file does exists in a folder on the server and I can use TIdFTP to connect OK. However no matter how I refer to path to the fileTIdFTP.Get keeps giving the error, Can't open : No such file or directory.

If I try to change directory first into the directory where the file is and then just use the filename I get the same error when I try to change directory.

What is the correct way to refer to the file so it downloads correctly?

For info,When I log into the server using Filezilla and the same credentials as used by TIdFTP, Filezilla seems to show the path as /MAMbase. I have tried with /MAMbase, ../MAMbase, ./MAMbase, /MAMbase/ and other variations without success.

[image: ((ssleay32.dll)]

The code I am using, after setting the connection paramers of host,post,username and password is below. Using either the path in the connect and get with just the filename or the get with the full path give the same error with any of the path formats I have used.

```
if (not fileexists(pathToCommonFiles + 'libeay32.dll'))  or (not fileexists(pathToCommonFiles + 'ssleay32.dll')) then
     begin
     try
       try
       IdFTP1.Connect ;
  //   IdFTP1.ChangeDir('MAMbase/');
  //   IdFTP1.Get('ssleay32.dll', pathToCommonFiles + 'libeay32.dll',true); 
       IdFTP1.Get('./MAMbase/ssleay32.dll',pathToCommonFiles + 'ssleay32.dll',true); 
       except on E: Exception do
            showmessage ( 'Could not make ftp connection for SSL files'  +slinebreak +
                          'Exception class name = '+E.ClassName+ slinebreak
                       +  'Exception message = '+E.Message);
       end;
     finally
        IdFTP1.quit ;
     end;

     end;
```

I have looked at similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063187/downloading-list-of-files-from-remote-ftp) and [here](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp/issues/45) but am no further forward.

(BTW pathToCommonFiles contains a trailing slash and it exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should prepare the local filenames ahead of time:

```pascal
LocalLibeayFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(pathToCommonFiles) + 'libeay32.dll';
LocalSsleayFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(pathToCommonFiles) + 'ssleay32.dll';
```

Or:

```pascal
LocalLibeayFile := TPath.Combine(pathToCommonFiles, 'libeay32.dll');
LocalSsleayFile := TPath.Combine(pathToCommonFiles, 'ssleay32.dll');
```

Then, either of these should work:

```pascal
if (not FileExists(LocalLibeayFile)) or (not FileExists(LocalSsleayFile)) then
begin
  ...
  IdFTP1.ChangeDir('/MAMbase');
  IdFTP1.Get('libeay32.dll', LocalLibeayFile, True);
  IdFTP1.Get('ssleay32.dll', LocalSsleayFile, True);
  ...
end;
```

```pascal
if (not FileExists(LocalLibeayFile)) or (not FileExists(LocalSsleayFile)) then
begin
  ...
  IdFTP1.Get('/MAMbase/libeay32.dll', LocalLibeayFile, True);
  IdFTP1.Get('/MAMbase/ssleay32.dll', LocalSsleayFile, True);
  ...
end;
```

Assuming the server drops you into the `/` folder initially, you can omit the leading `/`:

```pascal
IdFTP1.ChangeDir('MAMbase');
IdFTP1.Get('libeay32.dll', LocalLibeayFile, True);
IdFTP1.Get('ssleay32.dll', LocalSsleayFile, True);
```

```pascal
IdFTP1.Get('MAMbase/libeay32.dll', LocalLibeayFile, True);
IdFTP1.Get('MAMbase/ssleay32.dll', LocalSsleayFile, True);
```

If you are still getting the error, then you need to identify where it is actually coming from - the FTP server, or the local machine.  What is the actual class type of the `Exception` that is being raised?  If it is `EIdReplyRFCError`, the error is coming from the FTP server.  Otherwise, the error is coming from the local machine.

Comment: I'm afraid I still get the error using the code you supplied (which is perhaps not surprising as it is not much different to what I had) The error class is `EIdReplyRFCError` so it is coming from the server. But clearly the file is there as you can see by my Filezilla screen shot. The filezilla log shows that the connection parameters I use for filezilla and delphi put me in the / folder initially, so /MAMbase should be the correct path. I tried it with TIdFTP1.Passive:=True, :=false and without mentioning TIdFTP1.Passive at all. Same error.

Comment: Ah, as a test I tried getting TIdFTP1 to list the directory contents as soon as it connected and it showed me files I wasn't expecting. It seems Indy is putting me into the parent folder as I can see filenames like .bash_logout public_html, www and so on, including the parent folder of MAMbase. So I added the line `IdFTP1.ChangeDir('ApplicationUpdates/MAMbase');` and then the GET worked with just 'libeay32.dll' and 'ssleay32.dll'.  Don't know why Indy puts me in one place and filezilla puts me in another but problem is sovled now. Thank you for your time. Answer accepted.

Comment: "*It seems Indy is putting me into the parent folder*" - that is controlled by the server, not by Indy. The server decides which folder you are put into initially.  You may need to use the `TIdFTP.ClientInfo` property to mimic how Filezilla identifies itself to servers. By default, `TIdFTP` identifies itself as Indy. Maybe the server does not recognize that.